# ASP VB.NET GridView: Change Column cell text by column header name with AutogenerateColumn = True

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

Pulling my hair out, some help would be great.

I'm loading a GridView in ASP dynamically populating the results from an SQL Statement.  This page is for general queries so header names are pulled from the query results, no template.

What I'm trying to do is when a header is called i.e.. SSN (sensitive data column) I want to go through each cell in this specific column and mask the field.  Example: "###-##-####". before the page is displayed, and so all changes are kept on each page change and when the GridView is re-binded.

I looked over a couple events like GridView1_RowCreated, GridView1_OnDataBound

However, whenever I search for the header.text it's always empty! I can change it and set it, but it's never populated in these events. This leads me to believe I’m looking in the wrong place to do this update.

ie:

```
Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    Dim header As String

    ' DataControlRowType.DataRow - also tried this with checking HeaderText too.
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then

        For columnIndex As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1 Step 1
            header = e.Row.Cells(columnIndex).Text                
            Response.Write(header) ' Empty
            Response.Write("Cell") ' Will Display this for each header cell. 
            header = String.Empty         
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Would I need to do this on the Page_Load or PreRender?  Any ideas/examples would be great.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do this in Grid View PreRender event.

Comment: it's seems that with AutoGeneratedColumns = True on the GridView, that the Header cells are still not populated with Cell or HeaderText in PreRender or OnPreRender. I'm really at a loss now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can determine the special column by its header text you can find out the column index and then, when you found the specific column change the cell's text in the RowDataBound event.

This worked in my test:

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" />
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Beding:**

```
Partial Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Private _specialColumnName As String = "DEF"
    Private _specialColumnIndex As Integer = -1

    Private ReadOnly Property Data() As DataTable
        Get
            If Session("Default.Data") Is Nothing Then
                Dim value = New DataTable()

                Using connection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("your_connection_string")
                    Using command = connection.CreateCommand()
                        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM your_table"

                        Using adapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command)
                            adapter.Fill(value)
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using

                'value.Columns.Add("ABC", GetType(String))
                'value.Columns.Add("DEF", GetType(Integer))
                'value.Columns.Add("GHI", GetType(Boolean))

                'value.Rows.Add("A", 1, True)
                'value.Rows.Add("B", 2, False)
                'value.Rows.Add("C", 3, False)

                Session("Default.Data") = value
            End If

            Return CType(Session("Default.Data"), DataTable)
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        GridView1.DataSource = Data
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
            For index As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
                If e.Row.Cells(index).Text = _specialColumnName Then
                    _specialColumnIndex = index
                    Return
                End If
            Next
        ElseIf _specialColumnIndex > -1 AndAlso e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            e.Row.Cells(_specialColumnIndex).Text = "###"
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This still seems to be the problem. 'e.Row.Cells(index).Text'  is always empty, so there is nothing to test against.  The query is select * from [ThisTable] and the Gridview is set for AutogenerateColumns = True, and there are no Bound Fields in the <asp: columns becasue it's all dynamic.  I'm starting to think this is not an ability of .net to do this dynamically which is a shame.

Comment: I updated my answer and added a complete example (very simple but should be essentially the same thing you have described). Could you please test if this simple example works for you? Try to test with the manually created data (comment out the sql stuff and uncomment the data table generation code) and with a simple sql statement. As I said, this works for me. Maybe you have some special case? What kind of data source do you use? A `DataTable` or something else? Generally ASP.NET is capable of your described task.

Comment: Looks like that did the trick.  Thank you very much!!  Not sure if it's a .NET 2.0 thing but I had to prefix the types ie, DataTable and SQLClient with System.Data. first to get it working.  Wish I thought of that sooner,  I thought those types were missing in ASP.NET  I'm actually mixing a bit of Classic ASP with .NET to get some new features in this old hunk of junk.  I appreciate the kind help.

Comment: The `DataTable` class is in the `System.Data` namespace and the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and so on are in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace. So you either have to prefix the types with the according namespace or add a `Using System.Data` and `Using System.Data.SqlClient` on top of your code file; alternatively you can add namespaces on a project level under "References" in the project settings. In fact, normally, VB.NET projects have the `System.Data` namespace included on the project level from the very beginning. Maybe that may be turned of by a setting...

Comment: I believe the System.Data is not included becasue i'm not using a asp.net project.  i'm hand writting just a aspx page that i'm plugging into Classic ASP site.  Instead of Classes and Code Behind i'm just doing the function in <script> and using <asp: tags.  makes it easy and work nicely.  Thanks for the tip.  i''ll look into a project, might make things a little easier.

Comment: After a bit more research, what I’m finding is that the 'AllowSorting="True"' in the GridView parameters seems to be what is blocking and clears the HeaderText in the Gridview and then the customization in the GridView1_RowDataBound no longer works.  Most likely due to the auto generated postback links. Now I just have to figure out how to manually add header links and do all the sorting code manually.

Comment: I can most likely just loop the System.Data.DataTable() before i assign it to the gridview and get the header cell that way first. Then just make changes in the RowDataBound without needing to look at the header. Then i can re-enabled sorting and let the Gridview do the work.

Comment: Yes, if the DataTable is only for displaying purpose it might be easier to do your alteration directly on the data so you can use the GridView without any special data processing. Hope you get it to work!

Comment: it's working all except the Sorting. I have to writeup the gridview change events now the PageIndexChanging and Sorting now, for some reason it won't do it automaitcally on the datagrid now. (Datasource) most likely,  The page indexing is working. But anytime i try the sorting it crashes when i try on GridView1.Sort, and when i do it on the DataTable and assign it back to the Grid, no changes are seen after DataBind, so i'm testing different things now. So the fun continues :-) I've crashed the Dev web server a couple times so i'm testing on a local view in browser now.. haha

Comment: You have to handle the `GridView`'s `Sorting` and `PageIndexChanging` events to make paging and sorting work. Unfortunately I don't really use the `GridView` control so I can't really tell you alot about it. But since you got it working it isn't needed anyway. :)